# Complicated join and MAX() query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to make a join across 4 tables whilst picking the maximum (i.e. most recent) timestamp of test to associate with a person. For each student in a class, I want to lookup what their most recent test is, and get its ID and timestamp

```
SELECT students.ref, 
       students.fname, 
       students.sname, 
       classes.name AS 'group', 
       tests.id, 
       max(tests.timestamp)
FROM tests, students, classlinks, classes 
WHERE tests.ref=students.ref AND 
       classlinks.ref=students.ref AND 
       classlinks.classid=29 AND 
       tests.grade=2 AND 
       tests.subject=2 
GROUP BY students.ref
ORDER BY students.sname ASC, students.fname ASC
```

*looks* like it is perfect: for each student in a class, it gives the timestamp of their most recent test. Unfortunately, the test ID associated with that timestamp is wrong: it is just giving the test ID of a random test.

If I change the 'group by' to be

```
GROUP BY students.ref, tests.id
```

then the query matches correct test IDs to correct timestamps, but now there are several entries for each student. Does anyone have any advice so that I can get one row for each student, with correct test ID matched to correct most recent timestamp? Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Table descriptions:

```
mysql> describe students;
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ref    | varchar(50) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| fname  | varchar(22) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sname  | varchar(22) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| school | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| year   | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> describe classes;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| subject | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| type    | int(11)     | YES  |     | 1       |                |
| school  | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| year    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name    | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe classlinks;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ref     | varchar(50) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| subject | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| school  | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| classid | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| type    | int(11)     | YES  |     | 1       |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> describe tests;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| subject    | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| ref        | varchar(22) | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| test       | int(3)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| grade      | varchar(22) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| timestamp  | timestamp   | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                             |
| lastupdate | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
```

Comment: `classlinks.classid=29 AND classlinks.classid=classes.id` what's the point of this? a field can only have one value, so the only way this could possibly work is for records where classes.id is already 29.

Comment: thanks; corrected in sample query. Problem still remains!

Comment: please post your tables schema

Comment: this query should throw an error on a correctly configured mysql server, because all non-aggregated fields from your select need to be in your group by.

Comment: @Garytje This is the default behavior on MySQL so we have to live with it.

Comment: table schema  added to question. thanks.

Comment: @tornadof3 I am working on a solution but it will be better if you post sample data in sqlfiddle

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so (you haven't), provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so (and again, you haven't) , provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Thanks. Had never head of sqlfiddle before... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdea4/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the combination of `(ref,timestamp)` is unique in `tests` table. Here is my solution but I don't have any of your sample data to verify it. If it is incorrect than post a sample data so that I can test it.

**UPDATE**

Here is the update query which is working check the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0b698/5/0)

```
SELECT students.ref, 
  students.fname, 
  students.sname, 
  classes.name AS 'group', 
  tests.id, 
  T.timestamp
FROM (select ref,max(timestamp) as timestamp from tests group by ref)as T
    natural join tests, students, classlinks, classes 
WHERE
 T.ref=students.ref AND 
 classlinks.ref=students.ref AND
 classlinks.classid=classes.id AND 
 classlinks.classid=29 AND 
 tests.grade=2 AND 
 tests.subject=2
ORDER BY students.sname ASC, students.fname ASC
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. It's taken me a while to work out how to use sqlfiddle, but I've created one here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0b698/1

there is a slight syntax error, but I can't spot what it is?

Comment: @tornadof3 check the updated answer I think it is finally over :)

Comment: thank you so much! This works perfectly! (for me) a really complicated sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Using the logic in SQL the query can be written as follows, not sure about mySQL but hope the logic works.

```
Select ref
      ,fname
      ,sname
      ,ID
      ,group
      ,Timestamp

From
    (select
        S.ref
        ,S.fname
        ,S.sname,
        ,T.id
        ,classes.name AS 'group'
        ,T.timestamp
        from
            tests T,students S, classlinks, classes
        Where
            T.ref=S.ref and
            T.grade=2 AND 
            classlinks.ref=students.ref AND 
            classlinks.classid=29 AND 
            classlinks.classid=classes.id AND
            T.subject=2 ) A

    inner join

    (SELECT tests.ref        
            ,max(tests.timestamp) 
     FROM 
         tests 
     group by
         tests.ref
    ) B
    on
      A.ref=b.ref and
      A.timestamp = b.timestamp
```